# layout in vue.js2.5 / vuetify application

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

In  vue.js2.5 / vuetify application  I use next layout with 2 inputs when I want 2 columns on extra small devices:

```
                        <v-flex xs12 sm6>
                            <v-text-field
                                    label="Created at"
                                    v-model="artist_created_at_label"
                                    readonly disabled
                                    v-show="!is_insert"
                            ></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>

                        <v-flex xs12 sm6 class="pl-4">
                            <v-text-field
                                    label="Updated at"
                                    v-model="artist_updated_at_label"
                                    readonly disabled
                                    v-show="!is_insert && artist_updated_at_label"
                            ></v-text-field>
                        </v-flex>
```

I use

```
class="pl-4"
```

for right input( artist_updated_at_label ) to have distance from left input( artist_created_at_label ), but how to get rid of it 
 extra small devices as I do not need it in this case?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can access current viewport size with `$vuetify.breakpoint`
([docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid#breakpoint-object)).

It's reactive so you can make your class conditional, so that it only appears on [arbitrary sizes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/display) (e.g. `smAndUp` excludes `xs`).

```
:class="{'pl-4': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp}"
```